# View only displays nodes that has comments when adding comment count field

Tags: views, 8

On drupal 8 I am facing an issue with views.
I created a view listing all nodes of a certain content type.
I added basic fields, **Title, Date** content was created, and a **read more link**.
The view works fine with these fields, but when i add ***Comment Statistics: Comment count***, all nodes that don't have any comment don't show up in the view.
It only lists nodes that received comments.

Any idea on how to fix this ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it is you. Unable to re-produce. Here is a example view listing content nodes, two fields and the comments count.

[image: Drupal 8 view listing content and comment count]

I also exported the example view [example view](https://gist.github.com/steinmb/dbbdefbd397c4d443086eacdf86e0dc5) that you can import and test out for yourself.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I tried on a fresh drupal 8 and it went well, so it means there's something wrong with that install, which is a good thing because I'm also having trouble with flagged content. Flagged nodes appear multiple times in views. If four people flag a node (bookmark flag for ex.) it appears 4 times on the view ! I ticked the distinct option on the view's query settings but it didn't fix it, I should try that on the new install and see if it produces the same result. Thank you for taking time to help